# How to pass a line feature as a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer parameter to a geoprocessing service using the JSAPI?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

Can some one tell me whats wrong here.
The geoprocessing job always fails and i don't see much info in firebug to debug. This is my code to generate the feature set.

```
var inputFeature = {
    displayFieldName: "",
    hasM: true,
    hasZ: true,
    geometryType: "esriGeometryPolyline",
    spatialReference: {
        wkid: 3460,
        latestWkid: 3460
    },
    fields: [
    {
        name: "OBJECTID",
        type: "esriFieldTypeOID",
        alias: "OBJECTID"
    },
    {
        name: "RoadID",
        type: "esriFieldTypeString",
        alias: "RoadID",
        length: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Shape_Length",
        type: "esriFieldTypeDouble",
        alias: "Shape_Length"
    }
    ],
    features: [{
        geometry: geom,//poly line geometry returned from a query task
        attributes: { OBJECTID: 1, RoadID: $('#RoadIdTextBox').val(), Shape_Length: 0.00 }
    }],
    exceededTransferLimit: false
}

var searchRadius = {
    distance: $('#SearchRadius').val() / 1,
    units: "esriMeters"
}

var IRIParams = { "Input_Route_Features": inputFeature, "Search_Radius": searchRadius };

console.log(dojo.toJson(inputFeature));
gp.submitJob(IRIParams);

gp.on("status-update", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});`
```

This is the output when i console.log() inputFeature

```
{
        "displayFieldName": "",
        "hasM": true,
        "hasZ": true,
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
        "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3460, "latestWkid": 3460 },
        "fields": [{ "name": "OBJECTID", "type": "esriFieldTypeOID", "alias": "OBJECTID" },
            { "name": "RoadID", "type": "esriFieldTypeString", "alias": "RoadID", "length": 10 },
            { "name": "Shape_Length", "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble", "alias": "Shape_Length" }],
        "features": [{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "polyline", "paths": [[[1966832.8483635725, 3875011.726536308, 0, 1189], [1966841.088767071, 3875017.3918245276, 0, 1199]]],
                "_path": 0, "hasZ": true, "hasM": true, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3460 }
            }, "attributes": { "OBJECTID": 1, "RoadID": "10239011", "Shape_Length": 0 }
        }],
        "exceededTransferLimit": false
    }
```

It even fails when i paste and run the output in the services directory interface.

Comment: What's the error from the gp service when you paste into the rest endpoint?

Comment: When i changed the services execution mode to be synchronous:

Unable to complete operation.
Error executing tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the JSON to Features tool. I write my inputFeature value to a json file using a web method which is saved in a predefined location. After the json file is over written i call my gp service.

And from now on i will make sure none of my services will have complex data types as parameters.